# Setting cross platform time limit for function (while loop) in Python

Tags: python-2.7, time, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm looking for a way to set a time limit, a countdown. I will use this function to control the amount of time the user can run a while loop. Here's an example of how it's doing to run.

```
def run(strings, timeout=30):
    while timeout > 0:
        input = raw_input("prompts that will continue prompting as long as not timed out")
        if input != strings:
            #do something here, maybe be able to deduct off timer. 
        else:
            score += 1 
            print "%d /r" % timeout #print timeout
    return score
```

My example may not be very neat, but it's the general idea. The `timeout` will control the loop.

Can this be done for the `timer` library? Do I need a separate thread to handle the time while my function runs (prompting user)?